# Finding if two strings are equal structurally using scheme

Tags: function, scheme, conditional-statements

Write a Scheme predicate function that tests for the structural equality of two given lists. Two lists are structurally equal if they have the same list structure, although their atoms may be different.

(123) (456) is ok
(1(23))((12)3) is not ok

I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those are lists, not strings.  You have it right in the text of your question but not in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints. This one is a bit repetitive to write, because the question looks like homework I'll let you fill-in the details:

```
(define (structurally-equal l1 l2)
  (cond ( ? ; if both lists are null
         #t)
        ( ? ; if one of the lists is null but the other is not
         #f)
        ( ? ; if the `car` part of both lists is an atom
         (structurally-equal (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))
        ( ? ; if the `car` part of one of the lists is an atom but the other is not
         #f)
        (else
         (and (structurally-equal ? ?)     ; recur over the `car` of each list
              (structurally-equal ? ?))))) ; recur over the `cdr` of each list
```

Comment: Yeah I just needed hints on where to start more than anything.... Since I would like to understand what I am doing lol.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could approach this. The first one uses a function to generate an output that represents the list structure.

1. Think of a way that you could represent the structure of any list as a unique string or number, such that any lists with identical structure would have the same representation and no other list would generate the same output.
2. Write a function that analyses any list's structure and generates that output.
3. Run both lists through the function and compare the output.  If the same, they have the same structure.

The second one, which is the approach Oscar has taken, is to recur through both lists at the same time.  Here, you pass both lists to one function, which does this:

1. Is the first element of the first list identical (structurally) to the first element of the second?  If not, return false.
2. Are these first elements lists?  If so, return the result of `(and (recur on the first element of both lists) (recur on the rest of both lists))`
3. If not, return the result of `(recur on the rest of both lists)`.

The second approach is more efficient in the simple circumstance where you want to compare two lists.  It returns as soon as a difference is found, only having to process both lists in their entirety where both lists are, indeed, structurally identical.

If you had a large collection of lists and might want to compare any two at any time, the first approach can be more efficient as you can store the result and thus any list need only be processed once.  It also allows you to

- Organise your collection of lists by, for example, creating a hash map that groups together all lists with the same structure.
- Compare lists for *similarity* of structure (e.g. do these lists start and/or end with the same structure, even if they differ in the middle?)

I suspect, though, that your homework is best served by the second approach.